# Using android default buttons

Tags: android

I found these website http://androiddrawables.com/Buttons.html where you can check the differences between  `Android buttons` .

How can I use them? If I type `R.drawables.btn_star_big_on_pressed` the editor says it couldn't find the resource.

How can I use those default  `Android images` ?

I am using 4.0.

Comment: have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
android.R.drawable.btn_star
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know how to use them is:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="48px"
        android:layout_height="48px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_radio" />
```

to check available buttons type first letter after **drawable/**.
Then navigate to the button and you will see the selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Default resources for UI components depend on the device and platform version that your app is running on. For your button's to use them you would want to simply not declare a background resource.

Comment: If I place an ImageView ant set it's source to `@drawable/btn_star_big_on_pressed` the editor says that the specified resource could not be found but the image appears in the preview. So I think I have the image but I do not know how to use it.

Comment: The image appears in the preview because it is included in another android version.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is that you will go to the Android SDK folder/platforms/android-##/data/res/drawable-dpi and copy the icons from there into your own res folder.